# Mapping a property using an expression of MapStructs

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
class Product {
    Object obj;
}

class Object {
    Float amount;
}

class ObjectDto {
    Integer price;
}

class ProductMapper{

    @Mapping(expression = "java(this.convert(dto.getObject().getPrice(), decimals))", target = "object.amount")
    public abstract Product(ProductDto dto, decimals);

    protected Float convert(Integer price, decimals){
        price.floatValue();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to map by a Mapstruct expression an Integer to Float passing to a function the parameters and decimals but when the implementation is generated is not arriving correctly the parameter "decimals" and I can not map it.

It is possible?

The code of implementation looks like this:

```
class ProductMapperImpl {
    method(ObjectDto objectDto, Integer decimals){
        product.setObject(objectDtoToObject(dto.getObject()));
    }
    Object objectDtoToObject(ObjectDto objectDto){
        Object obj = new Object();
        obj.setAmount (this.convert(objectDto.getPrice());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your example is not complete.. is it? But if I guess what it should be, add `@Context` in front of `decimals` in both method signatures.

Comment: The code is an approximation of what I have but the @context I do not understand why use it in front of decimals. I've been researching more how to make this case and I think it's better to use the "qualifiedByName".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what about this (this is what I meant originally):

```java
@Mapper
public abstract class ProductMapper{

    @Mapping( target = "amount", source = "object.price" ); 
    public abstract Product toProduct(ProductDto dto, @Context Integer decimals);

    public Float createPrice(Integer price, @Context Integer decimals) {
       // do some Float stuff here
    }

}
```

BTW: I would not use a Float for an amount, but always a BigDecimal.. Just google on float / amount..